# display attribute values on category page in magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, categories

I have a `Brand` attribute (dropdown) that I created for products. The dropdown for this attribute displays 5 to 6 brands.

What I want is to display the attribute value of `brand` in the category page, and the value should be related only to those products which are currently displayed in the category page. So, if six products are displayed, then six brands should be displayed, selected by the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template `catalog/product/list.phtml`, near the top, there is a line like this:

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
```

This collection contains all the product objects that will be displayed on the page. If you want to echo those onto the page, do something like this:

```
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) {
    print $_product->getBrand();
} ?>
```

You will want to make sure that your brand attribute has been configured to set "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes". That will make sure that the attribute is loaded.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe